# SQL Join SQLzoo

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sqlite

There's a problem on SQLzoo under More Join operations for MySQL.
The problem asked is

**List the films released in the year 1978 ordered by the number of actors in the cast.**

The tables given are as follows, ord has value of 0 or 1, 1 for star role.

```
movie | actor | casting
id       id      movieid
yr       name    actorid
title             ord
budget
gross
director
```

I wrote my SQL query as follows, SQLzoo isn't telling me I have the right answer, but I believe my query to be correct. Can someone verify this and possibly tell me how to do this without a subquery please? Thanks!

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  movie.title, f.num_actors
FROM
  (SELECT
     casting.movieid,COUNT(casting.actorid) AS num_actors
   FROM
     casting
   GROUP BY
     casting.movieid ) f
JOIN
  movie ON f.movieid = movie.id
WHERE
  movie.yr = 1978
ORDER BY
  2 DESC
```

Comment: why would you use `ORDER BY 2 DESC`? Does that mean you are trying to order things by the second column in the `SELECT` statement? I'm beginning to learn SQL, so sorry if this is a newbie question.

Comment: @user1330974 yes order by n will just sort by nth column in the final table

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do the join first, then do the grouping:

```
SELECT movie.*
FROM movie
JOIN casting ON movie.id = casting.movieid
WHERE movie.yr = 1978
GROUP BY movie.id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: There are two SQL antipttterns in that.Very poor code.

Comment: @HLGEM could you explain the antipatterns in the above code please?

Comment: USe of select * and the very very bad incorrect use of group by.  Suggest you read the book on sql antipatterns, you can find it on Amazon.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT title, COUNT(actorid) AS actors FROM movie
JOIN casting ON id = movieid
WHERE yr = 1978
GROUP BY title
ORDER BY actors DESC
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please indent code with four spaces to enable syntax highlighting. This time, I have done it for you :) This page might be interesting: [Markdown help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT title,count(actorid) FROM movie join casting on movie.id=movieid join
actor on actor.id=actorid WHERE yr='1978' GROUP by title ORDER by
count(actorid) desc, title
```

Hi guys, I know I'm a bit late but gonna try to help still :) This is how I did it. Part of the instruction is to order it by the number of actors in the cast, then by title. Explains the last part of the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
select title, count(actorid)
from movie 
join casting on movie.id = movieid
where yr = 1978
group by title
order by count(actorid) desc, title asc
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like SQLzoo data is 'corrupted' right now and it is not accepting correct queries. Below will give you two entries which does not look to be correct.

select * from 
casting where movieid = 20136
and actorid = 179
order by ord

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with SQLZoo but you have to change the last part of your SQL from `2 DESC` to `f.num_actors DESC, title`. Below is the modified version of your sql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  movie.title, f.num_actors
 FROM
  (SELECT
     casting.movieid,COUNT(casting.actorid) AS num_actors
    FROM
    casting
    GROUP BY
    casting.movieid ) f
 JOIN movie ON f.movieid = movie.id
WHERE movie.yr = 1978
ORDER BY f.num_actors DESC, title
```

The other workaround without using inner select is:

```
SELECT title, count(casting.actorid)
 FROM movie 
           JOIN casting ON casting.movieid = movie.id
 WHERE yr=1978
 GROUP BY title
 ORDER BY count(casting.actorid) DESC, title
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is relatively simple

`select title, count(actorid) from movie 
join casting on movie.id=movieid
join actor on actor.id=actorid 
where yr=1978 group by title order by count(actorid) desc, title`